# How do you customize a WPF TextBox control (template) appearance?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, styles

TextBox seems to work differently from others...
Say you want a different font, rounded corners, different colors, a tiled image for the background, reduced padding above/below the text (when I change the font on an individual TextBox they get a little too tall but there's a lot of wasted space), etc.  How do you do this in Blend 4?

I'd like it to be in App.xaml so that it's used by default for all TextBox controls in the app.

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? what exactly r u trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

I think everything you mentioned can be done using controltemplates.What is not working ?

Check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It will get you started for sure